# How can i change this SQLite query that uses windows functions to one that doesn't?

Tags: sqlite

I am working with a python application that uses sqlite with a version that supports windows functions, using these tables as an example as they have a similar structure to the one I'm working on.

Table Students

| StudentID | StudentName |
| --- | --- |
| 5421 | John Smith |
| 6790 | Paul Jones |

Table Accounts

| AccountID | FkStudentID | MonthAccountCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AX_R12 | 5421 | September |
| AX_R55 | 6790 | September |

Table Schedules

| ScheduleID | FkAccountID | SubjectName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sch_8732 | AX_R12 | Calculus |
| Sch_8733 | AX_R12 | Spanish |
| Sch_8734 | AX_R55 | Calculus |

I would make this query

```
with cte as(
  Select *,row_number() over (partition by Students.StudentID) as idx
  from Schedule inner join Accounts on Schedule.FkAccountID=Accounts.AccountID
  inner join Students on Accounts.FkStudentID=Students.StudentID
  where MonthAccountCreated="September"
)
Select StudentID,StudentName,AccountID,MonthAccountCreated,
  max(case when idx=1 then SubjectName end) as Subject1,
  max(case when idx=2 then SubjectName end) as Subject2
from cte group by StudentID;
```

So i could get this result

| StudentID | StudentName | AccountID | MonthAccountCreated | Subject1 | Subject2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5421 | John Smith | AX_R12 | September | Calculus | Spanish |
| 6790 | Paul Jones | AX_R55 | September | Calculus |  |

The problem is that due to security concerns, the database was changed to use sqlcipher and the python libraries that use sqlcipher don't have support for windows functions and i am not allowed to change the version that is already there.

Is there a way to still get this result without using windows functions?

Comment: Would there always be a maximum of 2 subjects per student?

Comment: Do not use "cte" as a CTE alias. I know there are a bunch of tutorials showing this pattern,  but this is very-very wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do by taking "max" of SubjectName `max(case when idx=1 then SubjectName end)`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For this example there will be 2 subjects, in the  definitive one there will be a  maximum of 9 but the logic would be similar

Comment: The handling of unknown/variable number of subjects is a problem by itself.  You should first address that, then address the question you asked above.

Comment: @PChemGuy i use it to get the string name. Also, why shouldn't i use cte as a CTE alias? i  don't know why that is wrong if you could tell me i would really appreciate it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, 9 will be the only number of subjects, using my original query i would get at most in idx a 9. The app doesn't allow to add more than 9 subjects to a student due to their policies. In case a student has less than 9 in the column will be an empty string.  So by adding  up to _case when idx=9_ has worked as of now

Comment: Take a look at this, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming). It does not have a section on SQL, but the whole "naming" thing is a very general programming topic. Yes, there are often strong opposing opinions. Either way, the name should always help you navigate the code and understand it. And what exactly names like "cte" tell you? Not to mention that the whole idea behind the CTEs is that you can have multiple CTE blocks.